# taking a screenshot of user's current page in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is fo debugging purpose, please take into account the following:

1. the user logs in to his/her account so manually fetching a url will not work - the screenshot must happen together when the user access his admin pages.
2. would love to receive guidelines specific for ruby on rails and heroku (i guess heroku is not much an issue i just dump the screenshot to s3).

so ideally like i mentioned in #1, when a user access a page, my app also takes a screenshot of the entire page and dumps it in a tmp folder.

can anyone point me how to handle that?

Comment: To clarify: You want, from the server side, make a screenshot of what the client sees?

Comment: yes maybe like using a headless automated testing tool (eg capybara or selenium or something) but really really unsure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a screenshot of what the user is currently seeing, you have to have some code on the user's machine that uses the underlying operating system API to take the screenshot. The API calls involved are different for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

Ruby on Rails executes on the remote server and generates HTML and JavaScript etc. that is sent to the user's web browser. The HTML is rendered by the browser and the JavaScript executes within the browser's sandbox, where it has no direct access to the operating system API. The important point is that there is no direct interaction between the server-side code and the OS running on the user's computer. If this were possible then it would be a massive security hole.

Therefore it's not possible to do what you want programmatically unless you can first install a client-side program on the user's computer that can talk to your server-side code. It cannot be done using Ruby on Rails alone because it's a server-side web framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without a user sending a screenshot themselves.